# Recursively processing a string pattern

Tags: java, c++, logic

I have following kind of patterns;

1. MAX(MAX(V1,V2),V3)
2. MAX(MAX(V4),V5)
3. MAX(MAX(V6),MAX(V7))

I need to extract those MAX which has single argument
Example:

1. It should be null as no such match
2. I should get MAX and V4 as this is with single argument
3. I should get MAX , V6 and MAX , V7 as both have single argument

I am able to do this with iterative function , but I see here a pattern here and I think its possible to do it recursively. But I am not able to figure out how.
Can someone help me about it.

Comment: You could use regular expressions.

Comment: @therainmaker - can you sugegst how using regex ? Actually my problem is little more complex for example : MAX(MAX(abs(V1),V2)) , in this case I should get max abs and v1 together.

Comment: @Bankelaal - I've used regex.. If you want only *recursive* approach, then please let me know.. I will delete my answer

Comment: @Bankelaal - Ya.. You need to write a parser... Regex doesn't suit your needs

Comment: Yes I need kind of parser. The pattern is recursive in nature. A key word can take two arguments or single argument , I need to find the keyword which takes the single argument. I feel for example MAX(MAX(V1),MAX(V2)) , If I find the keyword say MAX and give in between ( and ) recursively and finally if I find there is only one V* inside () then I have found the candidate. But I am still thinking how to program for it.

Comment: Post your attempt, and we can probably help your get on the right line. Recursive parsing of expressions is typical standard for compilers, so it's a good pattern to learn.